# How do I answer questions on this site?

Tags: discussion, support

I found a solution to [a question on this site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55243/the-headphone-jack-on-my-macbook-pro-just-stopped-working-how-do-i-fix-it) that no one had provided my answer for and I wanted to share it with the world.  I cannot figure out how to answer a question.  Commenting takes "Reputation".  How do I do this?  I love this site idea but I am very frustrated right now.

Comment: As you see - 18 hours only have passed since this question & already you have over 50 rep points. The entry bar is there to stop fly-bys & spammers, not people who wish to actively participate. It doesn't take long to get that first 50 - now not only can you answer, you can comment on other people's posts too. Welcome to Ask Different ! :)

Answer (score 4):

The question you've mentioned ([The headphone jack on my MacBook Pro just stopped working. How do I fix it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55243/the-headphone-jack-on-my-macbook-pro-just-stopped-working-how-do-i-fix-it)) got protected automatically by the system because it attracted a lot of off-topic answers in the past (which got deleted so you can't see them). I've removed the protection and am looking forward to see your answer.

- To get some details about protected questions, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions.
- To learn about reputation (points), see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation
- To learn more about how this (and all other StackExchange) sites work, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score -1):

You can answer the vast majority of site questions without earning 10 reputation on a specific site. An association bonus of 100 doesn't count in the few questions that are "protected".

Anyone with 10 rep (association or earned otherwise can comment on anyone's questions or answers.

See the [help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/) and especially the [section on how to answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/answering) for more guidance.

Comment: Then I was going to just post the question and answer it myself, but I found out that you can only post every 20min... Thanks for your help.  I don't if you work for this site, but if you do, you should know this is a very unwelcome way for people to contribute.  I don't how the site can function when there are road blocks the whole way to building it up

Comment: Very few people 'work for this site'. The entire idea of SE is that it is edited & moderated by the users themselves, gaining powers with reputation, plus we have dedicated moderators, who have higher edit/delete powers.

Comment: @AaronTrimble extenuating circumstances -- the vast majority of our questions here don't have such a high bar on them for answering. The one you picked just happens to be a magnet for bad and off topic answers so it was protected.